# NDB Expando Model with dynamic TextProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do:

```
MyModel({'text': db.Text('text longer than 500 byets')})
```

But get:

```
BadValueError: Indexed value fb_education must be at most 500 bytes
```

I'm thinking this is just a carry over from this issue with the old db api.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/wLAwrjtsuks

Answer (score 5):

First create entity dynamically :

```
 kindOfEntity = "MyTable"
class DynamicEntity(ndb.Expando):
     @classmethod
     def _get_kind(cls):
        return kindOfEntity
```

then after to assign Text Properties run time/dynamically as shown below

```
dbObject = DynamicEntity()
key = "studentName"
value = "Vijay Kumbhani"
textProperties = ndb.TextProperty(key)
dbObject._properties[key] = {}
dbObject._values[key] = {}
dbObject._properties[key] = textProperties 
dbObject._values[key] = value
dbObject.put()
```

then after key properties assign with Text properties

Comment: Thanks. Same issue ate up my morning. This fixed it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a `db.Text`, part of the old API, with NDB, which isn't going to work.

To the best of my knowledge, there's no good way to set unindexed properties in an `Expando` in NDB, currently. You can set `_default_indexed = False` on your expando subclass, as (briefly) documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#3155), but that will make the default for all expando properties unindexed.

A better solution would be to avoid the use of `Expando` alltogether; there are relatively few compelling uses for it where you wouldn't be better served by defining a model (or even defining one dynamically).

Comment: Thanks Nick. The Expando I'm populating is part of the webapp2 auth package (webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.model). The ecosystem around it is nice, so I was hoping to keep that and have some unindexed data. Here's a link to the User model source: http://hilinkit.appspot.com/ymgpgv

Comment: @crizCraig Can you not just subclass the model, instead of using it as an expando?

Comment: Yes, it looks like I can subclass with: `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(config={'webapp2_extras.auth': {'user_model': MyUser}})`
But since I'm grabbing fields from the different oauth providers, I wanted to have a simple rule that allowed me to store stuff larger than 500B without manually making exceptions for each one.

Comment: You can set a single property indexed (while the others remain not indexed) if in every put of the kind you set the property like this: prop = ndb.GenericProperty("name", indexed=True)
prop._code_name = "name"
entity._properties["name"] = prop
prop._set_value(user, 'value for prop')

This only works for properties that can be indexed (does not work on TextProperty, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I know question is old. But I also googled for same solutions and not found any result.
So here receipt that works for me (I expand User() with "permissions" property):

```
prop = ndb.GenericProperty("permissions", indexed=False)
prop._code_name = "permissions"
user._properties["permissions"] = prop
prop._set_value(user, permissions)
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer was VERY use to me... Thanks!!!  I just wanted to add that it appears you can also create a specific property type using this technique (if you know the datatype you want to create).  When the entity is later retrieved, the dynamic property is set to the specific type instead of GenericProperty.  This can be handy for ndb.PickleProperty and ndb.JsonProperty values in particular (to get the in/out conversions).

```
prop = ndb.TextProperty("permissions", indexed=False)
prop._code_name = "permissions"
user._properties["permissions"] = prop
prop._set_value(user, permissions)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to just change one property of an entity to Text. But when you don't map your properties explicitly, Expando/Model seem to change all properties of an entity to GenericProperty (after get).

When you put those entities again (to change the desired property), it affects other existing TextProperties, changing then to regular strings.

Only the low-level datastore api seems to work:

https://gist.github.com/feroult/75b9ab32b463fe7f9e8a

You can call this from the remote_api_shell.py:

```
from yawp import *
yawp(kind).migrate(20, 'change_property_to_text', 'property_name')
```