# Dynamically setting a property in ndb object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

In my GAE based web app I load a NDB Entity and try to edit that. But the problem is the field I am going to edit is dynamically decided from a string so I can't hardcode it.

I tried these things but none worked

```
obj[fieldName] = newValue
obj.populate(fieldName,newValue)
obj.populate(Modlue._properties[fieldName] = newValue) #keyword can't be an expression
setattr(obj, fieldName,newValue) #value not being set
```

There must be some correct syntax to do that. Can anybody help me regarding that

Comment: The last one is correct. How are you verifying that the value is not being set?

Comment: Alternately you can use populate but pass a dictionary.  `obj.populate(**{fieldname:newValue})`  as populate takes a set of named arguments that correspond to the properties.

Comment: The difference is that if fieldName is not a defined Property of the model, setattr(...) just sets a local (non-persisted) attribute, while populate(**...) gives you a useful error.

Comment: **setattr function working statically assign properties in entity. but you are using set dynamic properties to go to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709893/ndb-expando-model-with-dynamic-textproperty/20233973#20233973)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [Expando class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/creating-entity-models#creating_an_expando_model_class)

You can safely replace `ndb.Model` with `ndb.Expando` in your model classes, your persisted entities will still be perfectly usable.

**Note**: However, it might not work the other way around; `ndb` will crash if you try to manipulate (fetch/put) an `ndb.Model` entity that has attributes that are not declared in its class.